# Local links ( in browsers ) on *nix systems

Tags: unix, browser, filesystems, url

On Windows I can access files directly from the browser ( or at least I have it configured currently, forget if it was native like this ) with the file:// protocol, so I can access files from say the C drive.

I'm wondering what the equivalent would be to accessing my files from the browser, if at all possible on a *nix system such as Debian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `file:///`.

example:

```
file:///home/username/
```

of course, replacing `username` with your username.

Comment: Notice that the third slash simply signifies the file system root.

Comment: Works in lynx!  What more do you need?